# Why can't a prvalue of array type be converted to the same type using static_cast?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    using type = int[2];
    static_cast<type>(type{1,2});  //#1
}
```

Clang and GCC both [complain](https://godbolt.org/z/PG4G1EbPr) that `#1` is ill-formed, and give weird diagnoses.

Clang reports

```
static_cast from 'int *' to 'type' (aka 'int [2]') is not allowed
```

GCC reports

```
invalid 'static_cast' from type 'type' {aka 'int [2]'} to type 'type' {aka 'int [2]'}
```

However, as per [expr.static.cast#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#4)

> An expression E can be explicitly converted to a type T if **there is an implicit conversion sequence** ([over.best.ics]) from E to T

Isn't that converts a type to the same type be called identity conversion?
[over.best.ics#general-8](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#general-8)

> If no conversions are required to match an argument to a parameter type, the implicit conversion sequence is the standard conversion sequence consisting of the identity conversion ([over.ics.scs]).

I think a crucial rule here is

> The sequence of conversions is an implicit conversion as defined in [conv], which means it is governed by the rules for initialization of an object or reference by a single expression ([dcl.init], [dcl.init.ref]).

That means, assume a result object would be `t` which will be initialized by the prvalue.

```cpp
type t = type{1,2};  // #2
```

`#2` is also rejected by Clang and GCC. However, such a case should be caught by [dcl.init.general#15.9](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#15.9)

> Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression. A standard conversion sequence ([conv]) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered. If the conversion cannot be done, the initialization is ill-formed. When initializing a bit-field with a value that it cannot represent, the resulting value of the bit-field is implementation-defined.

According to  [basic.lval#1.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#1.2)

> A prvalue is an expression whose evaluation initializes an object or computes the value of an operand of an operator, as specified by the context in which it appears, or an expression that has type cv void.

In which case, Isn't that a prvalue of type `type` cannot initialize the result object?

Clang assumes that array-to-pointer conversion applies to the operand. However, such a conversion is only permitted if the bullet steps into [expr.static.cast#8](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#8). In other words, the conversion should not apply here for the operand in bullet 4.

GCC gives a more nonreasonable diagnosis. I wonder why the explicit conversion is forbidden by Clang and GCC?

Comment: This does not seems directly related to prvalues: `type v {1,2}; static_cast<type>(v); v[0] = v[1];` also cause the same casting issue (despite `v` should be a glvalue here).

Comment: @JérômeRichard There's no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that can convert the glvalue `v` to a prvalue of array type.

Comment: [Existence of an implicit conversion sequence may be not the correct thing to check](http://wg21.link/cwg2243). _If no conversions are required to match an argument to a parameter type_ The problem is that there are no function parameters of array type.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer That would make many things to be nonreasonable. Consider [over.ics.list#6](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#6), assume the array is of a multidimensional array type. *if the parameter type is “array of N X” .... if there exists an implicit conversion sequence from each element of the initializer list to X*. It would be wrong. Since the element of the array is also an array type. there's no function parameter of that array type.

Comment: I think https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#footnote-119  apply to [over.ics.list]/6 as well

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Despite the `array of N X` is originally a reference type, however, `X` is not. I said `if there exists an implicit conversion sequence from each element of the initializer list to X` where `X` is array type.  Actually, I think it's vague here, why not use reference to `array of N X`?  which would be distinguishable with [over.ics.list#10](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#10), see https://godbolt.org/z/Pnjab1oxo  This issue may be caused by whether the parameter type is interpreted to an array or reference type.

Answer (score 4):

Raw arrays are difficult to keep in array form - in prvalue context an array [decays](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr#basic.lval-6) to a pointer.

But does it apply `static_cast` context also? The rules are outlined in [[expr.static.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast)...

We're not casting to a reference, so we skip the first 3 clauses and arrive at [[expr.static.cast]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#4):

> An expression `E` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` if there is an implicit conversion sequence ([[over.best.ics]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.best.ics)) from `E` to `T` ...

This won't work because ([[conv.general]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv#general-3)):

> An expression `E` can be implicitly converted to a type `T` if and only if the declaration
> `T t=E;` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`

And `int t[2] = int[2]{1, 2};` isn't well-formed. The only legal way to initialize an array is specified in [[dcl.init.general]/15.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#general-15.5):

> ... if the destination type is an array, the object is initialized as follows. Let *x*<sub>1</sub>, …, *x*<sub>k</sub> be the elements of the *expression-list*. ...  the i<sup>th</sup> array element is copy-initialized with *x*<sub>i</sub> for each 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *k*.

There is no provision for "unwrapping" `int[2]{1, 2}` into an *expression-list* here.

> Otherwise, the result object is direct-initialized from `E`.

Similarly this won't work for the same reason that `int x[2](int[2]{1, 2});` isn't well-formed.

Note that there is a special provision with regard to arrays in [aggregates](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.aggr#2.1), which allows for easy copying (e.g. `std::array`). There is no such treatment in raw arrays.

We skip over [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#5). 6, 7 don't apply. Which brings us to [[expr.static.cast]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#8):

> The lvalue-to-rvalue ([conv.lval]), **array-to-pointer** ([conv.array]), and function-to-pointer ([conv.func]) conversions **are applied** to the operand.
> . . .

So that's it, the cast is invalid. Both Clang and GCC seem to be correct. The error reporting differs slightly because Clang reports the decayed type, and GCC reports the original type.

As a workaround, cast to a reference type: `static_cast<type&&>(type{1,2});`.

Comment: Not much has changed in that area, but ok, links updated.

Comment: *The main issue is, in prvalue context an array decays to a pointer.* What' the relevant rule do you say that?

Comment: @xmh0511 [expr.basic.lval-6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr#basic.lval-6).

Comment: Do you think `type{1,2}` is a glvalue?

Comment: Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is direct-initialized with the initializer. That means the result object can be initialized from E.

Comment: *int t[2] = int[2]{1, 2}; isn't well-formed* For this case, I have the same opinion with Jens Maurer, see https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4582#issuecomment-817095762, we think it should be well-formed. For `direct-initialized from E`, you say it has the form `int x[2](int[2]{1, 2});`, it's vague here. It arguably says that they are not equivalent as per the current standard. It is also what I'm concerned about in that issue.